# Copy a range of cells until blank, into another worksheet at the next blank, usable from any sheet

Tags: vba, excel

first post.

After looking for 7 hours today,  I cant seem to find a cure for this issue. I have two worksheets, with the same headers.

"Manual Entries", that has 8 headers and data will change time to time. I want the macro to collect all filled cells below the headers, and post it into the B column that is next open row of "Automatic Entries" which has 9 headers, the first being the only different from "Manual Entries".

The issue is, no matter how I write it or record, I receive an error. Sometimes its about objects, other times it cant figure out the area. I have no idea how to fix this. Heres my code. I can give you errors based on what code changes you want because it changes everytime.

```
Sub EE() ' ' EE Macro '

'
    Sheets("Manual Entries").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-4, -2).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Enter DatA Here").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-11, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(5, 10).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9 End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to add, it doesnt work once I try to attach sheets to commands, in any combination. I want to be able to run this command from any sheet.. Right now the error is 1004 object define, and it was just after I recorded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following (untested) code probably does what you want:

```
Option Explicit
Sub EE()
    Dim wsME As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsME = Sheets("Manual Entries")
    Set wsData = Sheets("Automatic Entries")
    wsME.Range("A2:H" & wsME.Range("A" & wsME.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
        Destination:=wsData.Range("B" & (wsData.Range("B" & wsData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1))
End Sub
```